# Apptentive and React Native?

Tags: react-native, apptentive

I came across Apptentive and it looks very promising. however, it does not appear to integrate (currently) with react native. Is there a project for integrating the two that I am missing?

What other similar products, if any, currently support React Native?

Answer (score 1):

Apptentive does not support React-Native out of the box.  There may be a way to integrate the native SDK's, but I have not heard of or seen any projects do it yet.

If you give it a try I would love an update on how it went.

Answer (score 0):

There's are a couple React Native wrappers for Apptentive.

The best that I found is `react-native-apptentive-module`
https://github.com/ErikMediaMonks/react-native-apptentive-module

As of 10/19/17, it was working with React Native 46+.  However, I ran into an issue where it was not working with Cocoapods 1.3 (it seems to have been built for an earlier version of Cocoapods that kept Headers in a different place).

You can see my fork of the library at:
https://github.com/gwmccull/react-native-apptentive-module